# Why can't you have two AppRegistry.registerComponent lines?

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native

I'm teaching myself `React-Native` and I came across this strange roadblock.  Inside my `App.js` I'm trying to export a class and then use another file within my `App.js` which is inside the `somePage()` function. where I'm calling `<Header/>` in an attempt for that text to appear on my physical device upon hitting `refresh`.

It displays `<Login/>` perfectly, but not what's within the `somePage()` function.  My question is, why?

(I'm using `Expo` by the way, instead of having an `index.ios.js` file it's an `App.js` file that still supports cross platform development).

Here's my `App.js` file:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import Login from './components/Login';
import Header from './components/Header';

export default class Project extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Login/>
        );
    }
}

const somePage = () => (
    <Header/>
);

AppRegistry.registerComponent('someProject', () => Project);
AppRegistry.registerComponent('someProject', () => somePage);
```

Here's my `Header.js` file:

```
import React from 'react';
import {Text} from 'react-native';

const Header = () => {
    return <Text>Testing this out</Text>
}

export default Header;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The concept of react is that a parent component renders child components.  You only need to register once because the root component is the parent component of all other components.  Any other child or grandchild components you want to render must be descendants of the root component.  As a side note, you don't need to have `export default` in front of the `Project` component, because you aren't exporting it anywhere: you are registering it below.

To fix your app, you need to place the header component inside the registered root component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {AppRegistry, View } from 'react-native';
import Login from './components/Login';
import Header from './components/Header';

class Project extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View>
              <Header/>
              <Login/>
            </View>
        );
    }
}


AppRegistry.registerComponent('someProject', () => Project);
```

Comment: Actually, wait.  I need `export default class` in order for your code to work.  Otherwise, I get an error.

Comment: If you are using the project component somewhere else, you would need to export it.  If that's true, then you didn't provide the necessary code for me to help you.  Not my fault.

Comment: My guess is that you are using this same component to register for both android and iOS.  In that case, you would need to require it in the other directory.  But, again, you don't mention that in your question, so I have no way of knowing.  That's not enough reason to unaccept my answer, because my answer does solve the problem you presented.

Comment: I did mention it in the very last sentence of my post.

Comment: Yes, I saw that after I wrote my last comment.  I'm confused, where do you need to the Project component?

Comment: I have been struggling with this export default and why it is needed too.  Also, in my app the AppRegistry doesn't seem to do anything.  It seems that the CRNA initiated projects don't use the AppRegistry and need to export the component, which CRNA picks up.  In this link it states that "CRNA abstracts AppRegistry away":  https://medium.com/@inyono/using-react-native-storybook-with-create-react-native-app-471e531bb128